# Magento2.0 catalogProduct filter

Tags: magento, soap, filter, magento2, magento-2.0

I want to get products from `Magento 2.0.2` ce with `typeId != "bundle"` via `SOAP`. When i send this request:

```
<soap:Body>
    <def:catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
        <searchCriteria>
            <filterGroups>
                <item>
                    <filters>
                        <item>
                            <field>typeId</field>
                            <value>simple</value>
                            <conditionType>neq</conditionType>
                        </item>
                    </filters>
                </item>
            </filterGroups>
            <pageSize>111</pageSize>
            <currentPage>1</currentPage>
        </searchCriteria>
    </def:catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

I receive this response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
            <env:Code>
                <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
            </env:Code>
            <env:Reason>
                <env:Text xml:lang="en">Invalid attribute name: %1</env:Text>
            </env:Reason>
        </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I'm pretty sure that connection is good, i can receive products and filter them by name field. So, i faced with problems only when i tried to filter by typeId field.

How to get products from `Magento 2.0.2 ce` with `typeId != "bundle"` via `SOAP`? (i know that i can pull all products and then filter them in my code, but it will be better to filter them on the server side)